# Adding AWS Eventbridge rules for code commit to run lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit, aws-event-bridge

I am trying to add an eventbridge rule for whenever a codecommit repository is created trigger a lambda function. Below is my rule and I am not sure what to add on reference type or if is there is another rule that I can use.

```
  "source": [
    "aws.codecommit"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "CodeCommit Repository State Change"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "referenceType": ['']
    "event": ["referenceCreated"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't look like CodeCommit currently fires an EventBridge rule for when a repository is created, unfortunately ([See this AWS doc page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/monitoring-events.html)). You'll have to enable CloudTrail and use a CloudTrail event.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following event pattern<sup>1</sup>:

```json
{
  "source": ["aws.codecommit"],
  "detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": ["codecommit.amazonaws.com"],
    "eventName": ["CreateRepository"]
  }
}
```

Disclaimer<sup>2</sup>:

> To record events with a detail-type value of AWS API Call via CloudTrail, a CloudTrail trail with logging enabled is required.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>[Event name taken from underlying API call](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/APIReference/API_CreateRepository.html)</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>[Source for disclaimer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-ct-api-tutorial.html)</sub>